# Importing Python modules from files not in the Python's search path?

Tags: python, module

I want to import a module that is not in the Python's search path. I can think of two ways none of which are appealing to me:

1. add this to the python file `import sys; sys.path.append("/path/to/mymodule"); import mymodule`
2. update python path when running the python script `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/mymodule python myfile.py`

Is there any better/cleaner way to do this? If not, which one is preferred?

Comment: [Modifying Python’s Search Path](http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#inst-search-path)

Comment: Why is a sys.path.append not appealing to you? It seems very straightforward and good to me.

Comment: @mawimawi Because I haven't seen this pattern in any Python code that I have seen so far. That's what I'm doing now.

Comment: It's pretty common especially in the zc.buildout world.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a module given the full path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)